# eclipse + svn: how to manage whole workspace with svn

Tags: eclipse, svn, maven

I have a workspace with several projects that are build using maven.
I know that i can add each project separate to the svn, but how can i add my super-pom?
My super-pom is in the workspace directory and therefore not visible.

Can i configure eclipse to add the whole workspace directory to my svn?

Best regards

Comment: Have you found a more structured answer to your question? Maybe with m2e and indigo? Thanks

Comment: Currently I keep the root pom.xml in a separate eclipse-project (a simple directory) on the same level as the other projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly what you asked for, but I have used following pattern with svn-eclipse-maven combo quite successfully.

```
/pom.xml
   - contains only referenced projects

/parent/pom.xml
   - contains dependencies common to all projects, <dependencyManagement>, properties..
   - the stuff you would normally put in root pom

/procject(X|Y|Z|...)/pom.xml
   - normal project pom.xml:s
```

This way you only need to commit /pom.xml outside eclipse when you add or remove a project (witch is relatively rare). With this configuration parent and project:s are visible in eclipse and only root/reactor pom is not visible in eclipse.

Comment: That's how I'm currently doing it. ;) But I thought there would be the possibility to manage that with eclipse. Maybe with working sets or a plugin that adds a button like "Share workspace..."...

Comment: Sonatypes blog mentions SVN support (http://www.sonatype.com/people/2011/01/maven-ide-the-year-of-maven-eclipse-2/). I'm not sure if asked functionality is provided (seems good though). So you might have to wait until Indigo (eclipse 3.7) is out.